# How to call a custom constructor inside another class

Tags: c++

If I have 2 classes, one with a custom constructor, and the other with an instance of the first class. How do I create that instance with the custom constructor.

For example:

a.h

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::string input);
};
```

b.h

```
Class B
{
public:
    A a("Greetings");
};
```

This wouldn't work properly, it gives the error "expected a type specifier" on the string itself, and whenever I use a member of class A in class B, it says "expression must have a class type"

I'm assuming this means I'd need to make it

```
A a(std::string words);
```

But I'm not sure where or how I would define what the string should be.

Comment: `A a{"Greetings"};` will work. What you really need is one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/241631).

Answer (score 2):

Use the constructor's *initialization list*:

```
class A
{
public:
    A (std::string input);
};

class B
{
    A a;
public:
    B (std::string s) : a (s) {}; //This calls the constructor of A on 'a'
};
```

Also, in C++11 you can use the *uniform initializer syntax*:

```
class B
{
    A a {"Greetings"}.
    ...
};
```

But with this, you can only call the constructor with a compile-time constant.